# What does "起" mean in "饮食起居"

Tags: meaning

饮食起居: 饮(drink), 食(food), 起(?), 居(house).

What does "起" mean?

[百度百科](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%A5%AE%E9%A3%9F%E8%B5%B7%E5%B1%85):

> 饮食起居，拼音是yǐn shí qǐ jū，出自《祭杜祁公文》，解释为指人的日常生活。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

起居 is a word in and of itself.

《*规范*》defines it as:

> 活动和休息；指日常生活。

The breakdown goes something like this:

- 起 = 活动
- 居 = 休息

So 起 here basically means *to be active*.

Comment: could you please leave a reference to <规范>?

Comment: @Algebra I don't have a link for *Guifan*, but you can see《两岸》instead: https://www.moedict.tw/~%E8%B5%B7%E5%B1%85 "活動和休息；借指日常生活。"

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware of the *contrasting pairs* in this phrase.

- 飲 (to drink)
- 食 (to eat [not *food*])
- 起 (to rise up, get up > be active)
- 居 (to rest)

---

Like in English, when a pair of opposites in a category are stated, it sometimes means *all things* of that category.

- *The beautiful and the ugly*
- *All folks, old and young*

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole phrase 饮食起居 means your daily regimen. Otherwise, split it into pairs.

饮食：(your) drink and food = food and drink
起居：(your) everyday life

The place where you 起 (rise, start the day) is the place where you 居 (live, stop at the end of the day). Life is what happens in between. (Unless you are on holiday. I love the phrase 假日, 'false days' as a brilliant antonym to 饮食起居。 Days when you do something different.）

> What does "起" mean?

Where you start your day.

Comment: Very smart explaination.

Comment: The explanation of "假日" as "false day" is incorrect. It's simply "day for **rest**." You may refer to 康熙字典: 又【集韻】【韻會】居迓切【正韻】居亞切，音價。 **休沐** 也。【晉書·王尼傳】護軍與尼長假。【歐陽修·題跋】言旬休，皆休假也。